# C# Get cursor line in RichTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, cursor, richtextbox, line-numbers

In C#, I have a RichTextBox, and I want to get the current line of the cursor. Every answer I've found says to use:

```
int currentLine = richTextBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(richTextBox1.SelectionStart);
```

However, richTextBox1.SelectionStart only updates when you make changes to the text. If you move the cursor with the arrow keys, it does not update (I've verified this by printing SelectionStart as I move around).

How do I get the current line of the cursor, in a way that tracks it even if you use the arrow keys to move the cursor around?

I'm using VS2012 in Win8.

**Edit:** terrybozzio's answer showed the problem. For anyone else with this problem, you can't put the code in richTextBox1_TextChanged. You need to put it in richTextBox1_SelectionChanged.

Comment: In what event are you calling that method?

Comment: I was able to see the selection start change simply when I moved the arrow keys.

Comment: Can't you put the check in the keydown event? Then this will update when you move it around with the arrow keys.

Comment: I'm doing it in: richTextBox1_TextChanged. Oh, I see. That was stupid of me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First you need to get selectionstart,If there isn't 
any selected text, the value returned is the position of the caret(with offset in characters from the start of the text),then you call getlinefromcharindex and pass that value,place it in the selectionchanged event and even with arrow keys moving the caret position it will update:

```
private void richTextBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int index = richTextBox1.SelectionStart;
    int line = richTextBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(index);
    label1.Text = "cursor at line " + line.ToString();
}
```

Comment: This only returns the index of the specific line in the RichTextBox.Lines property. If word wrap is enabled, it will return wrong indices than what is displayed on the screen. Is there a way to distinguish between word-wrapped lines and logical lines without resorting to rendering and graphics?