# How to get Keyboard cursor position as Point in textbox

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to get Keyboard cursor position in TextBox or RichTextBox. On WinFrom I did this by using this code

```
Point p = rtb.GetPositionFromCharIndex(rtb.SelectionStart);
            
p.Y += (int)rtb.Font.GetHeight()*2;               
lstboxIntelli.Location = p;
lstboxbIntelli.Show();
ActiveControl = lstboxIntelli;
```

But in WPF I cant get `GetPositionFromCharIndex` property is there any other way to achieved this

I want to position a Listbox right under the keyboard cursor (Like Intellisense)

Any help will be appreciate

Comment: This can help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17909651/c-sharp-get-cursor-line-in-richtextbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In *WPF* `TextBox` you can get caret position in multiple ways:

1. By accessing [`TextBox.SelectionStart`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.selectionstart%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`TextBox.SelectionLength`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.selectionlength%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) properties.
2. [`TextBox.CaretIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.caretindex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property.

Unfortunately there is no `GetPositionFromCharIndex` in `TextBox` so you'll have to do a little trick using [`GetRectFromCharacterIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.getrectfromcharacterindex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get starting point for intellisense:

```
var rect = rtb.GetRectFromCharacterIndex(rtb.CaretIndex);
var point = rect.BottomRight;
```

*Note:* We are using `BottomRight` to make put intellisense in proper place.

Comment: I want Point values so i can add values on Y axis like this 
   `p.Y += (int)rtb.Font.GetHeight()*2;`

Comment: How to set
   `listbox.Location` property in WPF